# hotfix: Principal entity in an SQL application generates unnecessary updates - do it still effect EF 4.3.1?

Tags: entity-framework, concurrency, entity-framework-4.3

There is an issue reported on MSDN regarding concurrency exceptions which we think we are seeing.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2390624

It's quite an old issue, does it still effect EF 4.3.1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EF 4.1, 4.2, 4.3 and 4.3.1 are built on top of System.Data.Entity.dll that is part of .NET Framework. Since the issue is in System.Data.Entity.dll all the 4.x releases are affected by the problem. This should be fixed in .NET Framework 4.5 Beta so you can either request the hotfix or move to .NET Framework 4.5 and EF5